# React Router Error related to Link To

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to route the components from one to another, i am getting errors related to the react router link and the error for the react router is - [Failed to compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqlmJ.png) i have tried using react router and added its package to my project library.

here are code for the what i made for doing the route:-
1) [Index.js file][2]
2) [Navlink.js file][3]
3) [nav.js file][4]

In Index.js i have made a router in render method but it shows errors above.
In Navlink.js i have made a link return class which provide the link and all properties.
In nav.js file i have used the navlink by import navlink.js file.
but the errors keeps coming related to that link does'nt exist in react router and hashHistory does'nt exist in react router.

If anyone Knows Please help.

1)Index.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Homecontent from './homepage';
import Foo from './footer';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import ourAdvantages from './ouradvantage';
import LoginForm from './loginform';
import BoRegistration from './boregistration';
import VoRegistration from './voregistration';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('header'));
registerServiceWorker();
// ReactDOM.render(<Homecontent />, document.getElementById('homecontent'));
ReactDOM.render((
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="/loginform" component={LoginForm}>
      </Route>
    </Route>
), document.getElementById('homecontent'))
//ReactDOM.render(<LoginForm />, document.getElementById('loginform'));
//ReactDOM.render(<BoRegistration />, document.getElementById('boRegistration'));
//ReactDOM.render(<VoRegistration />, document.getElementById('voRegistration'));
//ReactDOM.render(<ourAdvantages />, document.getElementById('ouradvantages'));
ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById('footer'));
```

2) navLink.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <Link {...this.props} activeClassName="active"/>
  }
})
```

3) nav.js

```js
class NavMenu extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
      <li className="nav-item">
        <navLink to="/loginform/reactjs/react-router"><a className="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></navLink>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href="#">Our Advantages</a>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href="#">Offers</a>
      </li>
```

Comment: whats your version or `react-router` ?

Comment: @Panther can you give me the terminal command for checking react router version ?

Comment: `npm ls react-router` should give you `react-router` version. `npm ls` would list all modules and its version.

Comment: react router version is react-router@4.2.0 @Panther

Answer (score 13):

I hope you are using `react-router` 4x. In these new version you have to import `Link` from `react-router-dom`.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

You can check the same here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link.

But i hope you are following some tutorial or still using `react-router` 3.x style. So either you have to use correct version of `react-router` or follow the correct style of writing according to the version.

Comment: This thing i have done. but it shows that module not found.

Comment: This one is for v4 https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf.  However, you can do `npm uninstall react-router` and then do `npm install react-router@3.0.5 and continue with your current work.

Comment: Github page does provides your link to diff version docs here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
import { Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
```

Include `<Link>` where you include `Routes`

Answer (score 1):

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
```

You must be Route Navlink.jsx in  `<BrowserRouter></BrowserRouter` wrapped by a `BrowserRouter` in your `App.jsx`

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
    
       render(
      <BrowserRouter> 
        <Navlink.jsx/> **like this inside BrouserRouter**
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

dont' forget `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom` in `Navlink.jsx`

Answer (score -1):

If you have these errors:

> "The above error occurred in the  component:"

and:

> "Uncaught Error: link is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`."

then check that the link is import or not, and if your link element is `<Link>` (not in lower case `<link>`).

Comment: The answer contains writing errors. Consider fixing them for the answer to be clearer.