# How do I create a hyperlink to my nav bar with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, href

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div><h1>About Page</h1></div>
    )
  }
}

export default About;
```

I have been stuck for an hour trying to figure out how to create a hyperlink similar to href but with react. This is a new .js file and I want to create an external link to it so when I click the Nav Bar , instead of it directing me to blank page, it can direct me to my Twitter or something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class About extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Click here to know about us.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About Us</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default About;
```

Comment: ./src/components/aboutme.js
Attempted import error: 'Link' is not exported from 'react-router'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  react-router for it. 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/custom-link
it has a link element when you wrap in router you should be able to change the route..
hope it helps

Comment: this is a handy tool which I will study but I just want to be able to see my h1 and link to my Nav Bar for tonight before I go to sleep. It's been so frustrating, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div><h1>About Page</h1>
     <Link to="url" activeClassName="active">"Link Name"</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

For more explanation visit [here](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html)

Comment: I tried this and got an error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, also nothing but the Nav Bar is showing up in the webpage which is weird. Not even an H1 is showing up

Comment: Did you check the imports. 

I just missed it

Comment: what should I add in the imports that isn't there?

Comment: @hennyrose i modified my answer

Comment: am I supposed to export 'LINK' from react-router? that's the error that keeps coming up

Comment: import { Link } from 'react-router';. Did you notice this change??

Comment: ./src/components/aboutme.js
Attempted import error: 'Link' is not exported from 'react-router'.

Comment: while we're on the topic, why isn't my h1 showing up at all? I'm very confused.

Comment: @hennyrose try this:- import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';. for more clarity:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038034/react-router-error-related-to-link-to

Comment: thanks but I don't think any of this helped. Let me start from the beginning. I created a react project and I imported browserRouter on the index.js and I imported react-router on my app.js ... I created a new.js file in the components folder so I can create and about me page. I added an H1 element and for whatever odd reason, nothing shows up. I add sample code, and still nothing. Is there a reason why my code is not showing up? My Nav Bar is working fine, but anything other than that is not displaying??

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components) is a component of **react-router-dom** not `react-router`. Try changing your import as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class About extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Click here to know about us.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About Us</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default About;
```